# Is "pair of scissors" more correct than "scissors"?

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns

My wife always gives me a hard time when I say scissors; she insists the only correct way to refer to that cutting device is "pair of scissors". Is "pair of scissors" more correct than "scissors"?

Comment: There was recently a [question about pants](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/pants-why-is-it-plural), and as it happens, "pants" and "scissors" are both made fun of in Allan Sherman's song "One Hippopotami", so again I will recommend that people listen to it :) Here is a [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umlBrQoG6xk).

Comment: She corrected me last night; apparently I say "a scissors". Should I modify this question, or ask a new one?

Comment: I'd say *"a scissors" vs. "scissors"* is a different questions than *"pair of scissors" vs. "scissors".*

Comment: "Pair of scissors" and "the scissors" are both fine. "A scissors" is the phrase that bothers me. I have heard many teachers say this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both *scissors* and *pair of scissors* are correct; one is not more correct than the other. The context will usually determine where *pair* can be left out, and indeed, most simply leave it out where possible. Consider the following examples:

> - Darling, where are the scissors?
> - I can't find the scissors!
> - Who took the scissors?

In the above examples, one would rarely find *pair* used in those contexts. It is also colloquial to use *some* to refer to just one pair:

> - You need some scissors to do a perfect job.
> - I want some new scissors.

The above forms should not be used in formal situations. Thus:

> - You need a pair of scissors to do a perfect job.
> - I want a new pair of scissors.

In some situations, *pair* comes in handy:

> - I lost the scissors. We need to get a new pair.
> - Can't find your scissors? Want a new pair?

If one does not want to use *pair*, then one can also use *ones*:

> - I lost the scissors. We need to get new ones.
> - Can't find your scissors? Want new ones?

Similar "*pair*" words follow the same pattern. These are some common examples, not an exhaustive list:

---

Workshop/Gardening/Household tools:

- *calipers/callipers* (Mostly *caliper* these days!)
- *clippers* (Also *clipper*)
- *compasses*  (Although, increasingly, this is now simply called *compass*!!)
- *forceps*
- *pliers*
- *secateurs*
- *shears*
- *tongs*

---

Optical instruments/devices:

- *binoculars*
- *glasses/spectacles*
- *goggles*

---

Clothing worn below the waist:

- *breeches*
- *leggings*
- *long johns*
- *jeans*
- *jodhpurs*
- *pants/trousers* (including all varieties, such as *khakis*, and the like)
- *shorts*
- *tights*
- *trunks*
- *underpants/pants*

---

Singular items (mostly worn) that usually come in pairs:

- *chopsticks*
- *earrings*
- *gloves*
- *sandals*
- *shoes* (and all footwear types)
- *socks*
- *stockings*

---

One word that I do not think "*pair*" is ever used with, even though they come in pairs:

- *buttocks*

Comment: what about "a scissors"?

Comment: @antony.trupe: *Scissors* is a plural noun; thus "a scissors" would be wrong. To refer indefinitely to one unit, one should always use *pair*, as in "a pair of scissors". Further examples of correct usage when counting: `one pair of scissors`, `two pairs [of scissors]`, `several pairs`, `many pairs`, `a thousand pairs`. With the definite article *the* and the plural adjectives *these* and *those*, *pair* does not have to be used: `those scissors are terrible`, `try these scissors`, `the scissors are bad`, etc.

Comment: In the realm of cutting tools, "shears" and "clippers" follow the same mould as "scissors".

Comment: @J. M.: True. Thought of actually classifying along the lines of "cutting tools", "optical devices", etc... but too lazy! Will add your suggestions in about four hours!

Comment: @Jimi Oke : "cutting tools & coptial devices" category, as well as "pants", i prefer to use as a singular: i.e., "Where is my pants\scissors\spectacles" since they are in a sense shortened from "a pair of []" which is singular suggesting that taken together the constituent parts would be plural; but are useful, in most contexts at least, only as one unit, ergo e.g. 'scissors' is like a shorthand for 'pair of scissors' where "pair of" is used in the loose sense.

Comment: Can I say "In my pencil case there are scissors" or should I say "In my pencil case there are a pair of scissors"?

Answer (score 3):

Does she also complain that your pair of shoes don't match your pair of pants?  Or that your pair of socks need to be darned?

Just as we needn't refer to the above using *pair of*, there's nothing wrong with referring to a *pair of scissors* as simply *scissors*.

Comment: what about "a scissors"?

Answer (score 0):

The "pair of" construction is useful when trying to refer to multiple scissors. "Pairs of scissors" is much more elegant than "many scissors," "those two scissors," etc.

Comment: "Many scissors" and "those two scissors" are not inelegant – they're incorrect, since "scissors" is not countable.

Comment: Lots and lots of scissors!

Comment: (and yes - I'm aware that *lots of* is one of those phrases whose meaning has mutated. A "lot" of something originally meant - and still does mean, though it's no longer primary - a specified purchase or manufacturing quantity: "available in lots of 20", for example. Note to self: find out when its primary meaning changed to the current "synonym for *many*"...)