# Does (or did) "a trouser" or "a scissor" have a meaning?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number

We say *(a pair of) trousers*, *(a pair of) scissors*. For these two particular words, is/was there something like "**a trouser**" or "**a scissor**"? Did it use to mean anything?

E.g. in Czech, the word for scissors is also plural but is derived from "knives". So I was wondering if the pair-words like these are derived from some (now forgotten) words with a meaning in singular. Similarly, the Slovak word for *trousers* is a plural of a Czech word meaning "a single trouser leg". (Czech and Slovak are very close.)

Comment: Related: [Why is the word “pants” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/why-is-the-word-pants-plural)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7215 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17403

Comment: The _pair_ part is a **Dual** marker; _trousers,_ like _pants, panties, glasses, spectacles, binoculars, legs, arms, feet, twins,_ and _thumbs_, are things that occur in pairs and couples, and are thus quantified with _pair/couple of_. But of course these things are mostly singular; it's only the human-projected dual nature of the objects that qualifies as a plural. P-I-E had [dual inflections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)); English has almost no inflection, so English duals are all special words like the ones above, or _both_ or _either_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, OE had some dual forms, but they went the way of all things. I seem to remember that the pronouns tended to end in *-t*, which I could never tell was because of *we two* or just the general *t-* used in second persons (think *tu, te*).

Comment: @tchrist: OE wit (we two), git (you two). Modern English still has a dual:  yiz, youze, yous.

Comment: @TRomano You’ve misunderstood what I said about OE dual pronouns, which was that I questions whether the trailing *-t* was a second person indicator of its own, as seen in *thou, Du, tu* from various languages, or whether it had migrate thither from people continuously following it with the dual number, which begins with a *t-*.  That is, if you say *we two* often enough, it could end up reanalysed as *wit* for a pronoun; see *an apron*. As for Modern English having a dual, no, it does not. Those odd forms you have listed are at most mere regionalisms existing outside of the standard language.

Comment: @tchrist: First, I was just confirming your memory: "I *seem to remember* that the pronouns tended to end it -t". In the nominative, they do indeed end in -t.  But youze/yiz have very widespread use, though they're *considered to be* uneducated and nonstandard.  They probably would be in even more widespread use than they are, if it weren't for the fact that people had their mouths washed out with soap when they used them :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Scissors](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scissors)* apparently derives form the plural of the Latin cīsōrium for cutting tool, as does chisel.

*Scissor* is used in modern times in the singular as a verb, so "a scissor" is not necessarily (grammatically) wrong.

The [excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/why-is-the-word-pants-plural) FumbleFingers pointed to for pants covers that subject fully.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of tools in English that are made of two parts and are plural: *shears, scissors, tweezers, pliers, clippers, tongs, bellows, pincers*. English uses plurals for these, but that doesn't mean that they come from a singular word that meant just one of the two parts.

Consider *tongs*. This word was derived from the Old English word *tang* (plural *tangan*) which was singular and meant *a pair of tongs*. The cognates in Danish (*tang*, meaning *tongs* or *forceps*), German (*Zange*, meaning *pliers, pincers,* or *tongs*), Dutch (*tang*, meaning *pliers* or *tongs*) are all singular. The first citation the OED has for a plural form meaning *"a pair of tongs"* is from 890, and the last for a singular form meaning *"a pair of tongs"* is from 1480. So somewhere between late Old English and Middle English, it changed its plurality.

The same thing happened with *bellows*. It (bælg) was singular in Old English, and the last singular use the OED knows about is from the 15th century.

Answer (score 2):

As you suspected, the OED derives trousers from “trouse” referring to an article of clothing later described as “drawers or knee-breeches”.

Singular “scissor” is uncommon but OED cites several sources where authors have used it in place of the more common plural. A more common use of the singular form is to form compound words as in “scissor-hands”. Both forms seem to be used since being introduced to English by Anglo-Normans. A better fit to your Czech example may be “shears” where the singular form is usually employed as a verb meaning “to cut”.

Comment: "Shear" as a *verb*  does not exactly qualify as the singular form of the plural *noun* "shears."

Comment: @BrianDonovan has very cleverly conflated word usage with word form. Surely no reasonable person will deny “shear” _exactly qualifies_ as “shear”.

Comment: @technolepsy: I don't understand what point you're trying to make. *Scissor* can be a verb, or it can be a singular noun that only really occurs as a combining form or adjectival. *Shear* is ***exactly the same way***.

Comment: @Marthaª: You are, of course, correct. Apparently I have a peculiar aversion to the use of scissor as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find that it is not necessarily incorrect to use "a pants" or "a scissors". Historically a pant was a single leg covering. Pants are now a garment with two legs as attached. If one leg is removed the garment is considered incomplete. Therefore "a pants" is a recognized garment of clothing that has two **Pant Legs** and the use of "a" refers to "A Garment" called pants. The same can be applied to scissors - originally derived from Latin for "cutting tool". Without both blades a scissors does not transform into a "scissor". In effect it ceases to be a cutting tool. Hence a "scissors" is cutting tool with two blades that "shear".

Consider: in our developing language it is somewhat anachronistic that some (especially in the tertiary world) still choose to enforce historic (and often poorly understood) conventions.