# His politics is not good/ His politics are not good

Tags: verb-agreement

I have a doubt whether 'His mathematics is bad' is correct or 'His mathematics are bad' is correct ?

Comment: ShreevatsaR's answer to *[What is the difference between a “singular noun” and a “plural noun treated as singular”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4984/77227)* has some relevant information.

Comment: Related: [“That’s how Physics work” or “That’s how Physics works”?](/q/346291/26083)

Comment: Also related: [Are words like “scissors” plural?](//english.stackexchange.com/q/211713/26083) and [When using the noun scissors as singular is correct](/q/400138/26083)

Answer (score 1):

Just as you would say, "His pants **are** quite torn," you would also say, "His mathematics **are** bad."

Comment: Using [pants as a plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/why-is-the-word-pants-plural) is probably not the best comparison to make.